# Create Button in Xcode Playgrounds with SpriteKit (Swift)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to create a button in Xcode Playgrounds using SpriteKit and the touchesEnded function, but the following code hasn't been working for me. The backButtonTriggerBox appears on the screen, but when I click on it nothing happens.

EDIT: I updated the code so that everything is under one class, but it still doesn't seem to work.

```
struct myVariables {
    static var backButtonTriggerBox = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.red, size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 15))
}

class SpriteScene: SKScene {
    class func initialLoad() {
        let view = SKView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 550, height: 575))
        let scene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 550, height: 575))
        scene.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFit
        view.presentScene(scene)
        PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view

        let backButtonTriggerBox = myVariables.backButtonTriggerBox

        backButtonTriggerBox.position = CGPoint(x: 275, y: 13)

        myVariables.backButtonTriggerBox = backButtonTriggerBox

        scene.addChild(backButtonTriggerBox)
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let touchLocation = touch!.location(in: scene!)

        let backButtonTriggerBox = myVariables.backButtonTriggerBox

        if backButtonTriggerBox.contains(touchLocation) {
            print("hi")
        }
    }
}

SpriteScene.initialLoad()
```

Comment: Why not add a couple of `print` statements to your `touchesBegan` - one for the button's frame another for the touch location. you can then see what's going on.

Comment: I tried that before, but I still got no result.

Comment: No result? You mean the 'print' statements didn't fire? That should tell you something.

Comment: what is PlaygroundPage ? I get an error when running your code saying unresolved indentifier 'PlaygroundPage'

Comment: PlaygroundPage is a class under the PlaygroundSupport framework. You have to import PlaygroundSupport at the top of the code.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that your Sprite is not added to your scene? according to your sample code it is added to `scene` and the touchesEnded is `SpriteScene`. The button isn't even in the Scene code block

Comment: I edited my code so that everything is under one class, but it still does not seem to work. I also changed the touch!.location(in: scene!) to check for a touch in my scene.